# Setting input needed from programm opened in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a program that open with a bat file

```
cd "C:\Users\Stackoverflow\Desktop\win64exe"
xdag.exe -m 1 54.37.158.221:13654
```

The program opens up in cmd and asks for a password, i need to type in(note its still the same cmd).
This is what i do next:

```
 cd "C:\Users\Stackoverflow\Desktop\win64exe"
 xdag.exe -m 1 54.37.158.221:13654
 passworttest1234
```

This doesnt type in anything... i also tried setting a timeout which didn't help

Comment: If it read stdin, and a lot of password prompts DON'T. `Echo password | xdag.exe -m 1 54.37.158.221:13654`

Comment: Another option may be to run it with a `-?`, `/?`, `-h` or `-help` argument to see if there's an option to take the password as another argument. Alternatively tell us the real name of the program and somebody may have specific experience with it.

Comment: @ACatInLove, the space between the password and the pipe must be removed for it not to be output too: `echo(password| xdag.exe ...` (the `(` avoids problems with `echo` and certain characters)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if the program reads from `STDIN`, one can do

```
echo Password123| xdag.exe
```

This is quite insecure, but can be improved by encrypting it -> `CERTUTIL`

---

Otherwise, if possible, one can

```
xdag.exe -Password Password123
```

---

If none of those works, one can resort to use a VBS `sendKey`. What is does is:

- Start xdag.exe
- Enter password by emulating pressing key on keyboard

```
@echo off
start xdag.exe -m 1 54.37.158.221:13654

 echo Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > "%TEMP%\pass.vbs"
 echo WshShell.SendKeys "Password123{ENTER}"               >>"%TEMP%\pass.vbs"

cscript //nologo "%TEMP%\pass.vbs"
del /f /s /q "%TEMP%\pass.vbs"
```